# How should I efficiently label the rows of a dataframe by value?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of trips with a column of how the trip was made similar to column "a" below.

My goal is to add a new column of data to each row according to the value of column "a".

The function below works, but seems like an overly complicated way of accomplishing a fairly simple objective.

`new_var <- 0` seems likely to cause a bug.

If I don't attach the dataframe and call the column that way the function does not work, which is obviously not great.

Is there an obviously better way to do this?

```
a <- c("On the Subway", "On a train", "Driving","On the Subway", "On a train", "Driving","On the Subway", "On a train", "Driving")
b <- c(1,15,3,54,5,32,7,76,9)
my_dataframe <- data.frame(a,b)

new_var <- 0
carbon_func <- function(variable){

  new_var[variable == 'On the subway'] <- 0.014
  new_var[variable == 'On a train'] <- 0.014
  new_var[variable == 'On a bus'] <- 0.068
  new_var[variable == 'Motorcycling'] <- 0.072
  new_var[variable == 'Driving'] <- 0.12
  new_var[variable == 'In a taxi or rideshare'] <- 0.12
  new_var[variable == 'Flying'] <- 0.285
  new_var[variable == 'Cycling'] <- 0
  new_var[variable == 'Walking'] <- 0

  return(new_var)

}

attach(my_dataframe)
my_dataframe$Carbon_Footprint <- carbon_func(a)
detach(my_dataframe)
```

I've explored using a dictionary type thing like below but haven't found a working  alternative to what is posted

```
standardized_footprints <- c(0.014, 0.014, 0.068, 0.072, 0.12, 0.12, 0.285)
names(standardized_footprints) <- c('On the subway', 'On a train', 'On a bus', 'Motorcycling', 'Driving', 'In a taxi or rideshare', 'Flying')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the named vector, we can match the column to get the values

```
my_dataframe$Carbon_Footprint <- standardized_footprints[as.character(my_dataframe$a)]
my_dataframe$Carbon_Footprint
#[1] 0.014 0.014 0.120 0.014 0.014 0.120 0.014 0.014 0.120
```

But, one thing to note is the names should match the column values to do an exact match.  If there are entries where we have `On the subway` and the actual value is `On the Subway`, it is not a match.

#### data

```
standardized_footprints <- c(0.014, 0.014, 0.068, 0.072, 0.12, 0.12, 0.285)
names(standardized_footprints) <- c('On the Subway', 'On a train', 
         'On a bus', 'Motorcycling', 'Driving', 'In a taxi or rideshare', 'Flying')
```

Comment: awesome, it's output from Google maps so the names of each transportation type should be consistent.